# iOS: Warning message "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *(*)(const char *, int)'"

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I have an error message on the 2nd `NSLog` for the `%c`:

> for info, here is the type of 'index' char  =>  *index(const char *, int) __POSIX_C_DEPRECATED(200112L);

I don't understand what type I have to put here:

```
@try {
     [[cellToFill valueForKey:@"_textField"] setAutocapitalizationType: [[color valueForKey:@"textField.autocapitalizationType"] integerValue]];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"Char at index %c cannot be found", index); 
}
```

What is the good type to put in the NSLog to avoid that warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably written the wrong identifier, `index`, in your `NSLog()` call.

You code suggests you believe `index` is a character variable (e.g. declared as `char index;`) somewhere.

The error message states that `index` is of type `char *(*)(const char *, int)`, that is: *a pointer to a function which takes a character pointer and an integer value and returns a character pointer*.

Now it just happens there is a standard C library function [`index()`](http://manpages.org/index/3) of exactly that type.

Conclusion: you have mistyped your variable name as `index`, or typed it where it is out of scape, and therefore are getting the C library function – if you just write a function name in (Objective-)C you get a value which is a pointer to the function, exactly as your error message describes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `char *` is not a character but it is a pointer to a string, you can try changing the `%c` to `%s`.

If you use a standard `char` you can log it with a `%c`.

Comment: @ΩlostA Can you add the `index` initialization?